# D3: how to create input elements followed by label text?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array `var brands = ['Option1', 'Option2']`. I want to use D3 to output labelled radio buttons as follows:

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="brand" value="Option1" checked="true"/> Option1
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="brand" value="Option2" /> Option2
</label>
```

This is my D3, but it's not quite working:

```
var radios = d3.select('.panel.left').selectAll('input[name="brand"]').data(brands);
var labels = radios.enter()
        .append("label")
        .attr("for", function(d) { return d; })
        .text(function(d) { return d; })
        .append("input")
        .attr("type", "radio")
        .attr("name", "brand")
        .attr("value", function(d) { return d; })
        .attr('checked', function(d) { if (d === brands[0]) { return 'checked' }; });
d3.selectAll('input[name="brand"]').on('change', function() {
  renderValues(this.value);
});
```

It's very close to working, but it outputs this:

```
<label>
  Option1 <input type="radio" name="brand" value="Option1" checked="true" />
</label>
<label>
  Option2 <input type="radio" name="brand" value="Option2" />
</label>
```

No matter what I do, I can't figure out how to put the text after the `<input>` element. What should I be doing differently?

It would also be nice if I didn't have to re-select the input elements to add a listener, at the end.

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/04/using-html-inputs-with-d3js.html)?

Comment: Thanks, but unless I'm missing something, the ordering of all the input and label elements in that tutorial is already hard-coded into the HTML. I'm interested in generating them for a dynamic list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this at the end of your script:

```
d3.selectAll("label")
    .data(brands)
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

And delete these lines:

```
.attr("for", function(d) { return d; })
.text(function(d) { return d; })
```

You don't need to re-select the input. After the .append("input") add the listener:

```
.append("input")
.on('change', function() {
  renderValues(this.value);
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I didn't need to re-bind the data, I just did `d3.selectAll("label").append("text").text(function(d) { return d; });`. Clever to use a SVG text element.